# ClickOnce install dialog language

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, clickonce, publish

I tried to publish my first c# winform application using clickonce. In clickonce, I set the language to Slovak. After publishing, it shows me the entire installation dialog and the upgrade in English. The language option should set the language of the installation dialog to Slovak? Or does it serve a different purpose?

Comment: What is the computer's locale/culture set to where you are testing the clickonce? Creating a localized application is a little more involved than just setting the language. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/localizing-clickonce-applications?view=vs-2022

Comment: Go to windows > Settings > Time & Language and change the language. Does this method can change the language of the installation dialog.